# In app eMail with Cordova/PhoneGap without opening an modal eMail window

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I would like to send an eMail out of my app but directly out of my app without opening an modal eMail window.

I found some examples by using native code and calling an modal eMail window by using the cordova *exec* function and passing the parameters like:

```
var args = {
  subject: 'Subject',
  body: 'message',
  toRecipients: 'recipients'
};
cordova.exec(null, null, "EmailComposer", "showEmailComposer", [args]);
```

A really simple and nice way.
But I would like to send the eMail directly out of my application like the native app invy is doing it.

[image: Sending an eMail directly from app]

Do somebody know how to do it or did somebody hear about something like that?

Thanks in advance
yves

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to send an email from the user's mail accounts (that are saved for Mail.app) without showing them an email modal? Sorry if I missed the exact question, but if that's it I don't think it's possible.

You can use native elements in the app to trigger an email server somewhere to send an email, but I don't believe that permissions even exist for you to send an email without using the modal or getting the user's email credentials directly, like, by having them type them out again.

Comment: You got it totally right.
Thanks for your answer. I figured out as well that I have to use an ajax call to an email server and send the eMail through a php script.